# Detect Host Disconnect | Unity - Netcode for Gameobjects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I am experimenting with Netcode for Gameobjects in Unity in combination with Facepunch.Steamworks and the [FacepunchTransport](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/multiplayer-community-contributions/blob/main/Transports/com.community.netcode.transport.facepunch/Runtime/FacepunchTransport.cs).

I now want FOR THE HOST to detect whenever he disconnected, so i can put the Host into the MainMenu again.

For clients to detect if the host disconnected, i do it that way:

```cs
private void OnEnable() {
    NetworkManager.Singleton.OnClientDisconnectCallback += OnClientDisconnectCallback;
}

private void OnDisable() {
    NetworkManager.Singleton.OnClientDisconnectCallback -= OnClientDisconnectCallback;
}

private void OnClientDisconnectCallback(ulong id) {
    Debug.Log("OnClientDisconnectCallback: " + id.ToString());

    if (IsClient) {
        if (id == 0) { // 0 = host?!
            LobbySaver.instance.currentLobby?.Leave();
            LobbySaver.instance.currentLobby = null;
            NetworkManager.Singleton.Shutdown();

            SceneManager.LoadScene("MainMenu");
        }
    }
}
```

But of course, the OnClientDisconnectCallback does not fire for the Host himself, as i cannot see the "OnClientDisconnectCallback" Debug.Log.

**So my questions are:**

- Is there some better way to detect host disconnection?
- How can i let the host himself know he disconnected?

*Thanks for any help in advance!*

Comment: Are you talking about using UGS or a LAN?

Comment: I use FacepunchTransport with Steam Sockets.

Comment: Sorry, but maybe I don't get it. UNGO is one thing, UGS is another and the Steam networking API layer is another. What are you trying to achieve by combining them?

Comment: i don't use any unity game services, i use steams socket connections with the Facepunch Transport and Facepunch.Steamworks for Steam Lobbies, etc.

Comment: See: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/multiplayer-community-contributions/tree/main/Transports

Comment: OK, you didn't make it clear the first time. So you're using UNGO, but the Transport layer is provided by Steam's networking layer. And you want to know how to detect a host leaving a Steam Lobby? Or when he drops the connection?

Comment: @TheNomad Yes maybe a bit unclear ._. I wanna detect on host side if he lost internet connection, in best case with the given tools/features, not without doing it manually with a ping to somewhere or so. He stays in the scene as if nothing happened in that case, just of course the networked stuff will not work. I just wanna send him back to the main menu with an error message saying "connection lost" or whatever. Greetings

Comment: For voluntary dc-s, try `OnDisconnected()` or `OnConnectionChanged()` in FP's `ConnectionManager` wrapper. You have the param `ConnectionInfo` with `EndReason` and `State`. For connection loss, if that's not enough, try `OnTransportFailure()` in UNGO's Transport layer. Normally, using a socket connection needs a periodic messaging system for keep-alive checks. (usually called ping-pong or heartbeat). When they fail (meaning a pong/hb response) isn't received in time, the connection is closed locally because the *real* connection is lost. If it doesn't work, you'll need to implement your  own.

Comment: I tried `OnTransportFailure()` already without success. For the ConnectionManager, which is used in FacepunchTransport.cs, I don't know how i could properly use it in my own script without modifying it, as there, the connectionManager is private. But also, when i tried using the Send Method `NetworkManager.Singleton.NetworkConfig.NetworkTransport.Send(ulong clientId, ArraySegment<byte> payload, NetworkDelivery networkDelivery)`, which uses the connectionManager, it throws a null reference error for the connectionManager, so even when making it public, it seems to not be present anymore later

Comment: Ah I now see the `connectionManager` is client-side. Server-side you need the `socketManager`. It features the same 2 functions you can use to test the connection.